# Skyrim text is in Chinese. How do I change it to English?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I got *The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim* (Legendary Edition), but all the text is in Chinese. How can I switch it to English? I've already tried searching for the option to do so, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Did you purchase it digitally? If so, which region did you purchase it from? If you didn't purchase it digitally, where did you purchase the disk from? And is your console language set to English, or something else?

Comment: I assumed you were on a console for some reason... are you on a console, or PC?

Answer (score 4):

If on PC, this from the [Bethesda Support Page](http://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/23433/~/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-the-subtitles-in-the-elder-scrolls-v%3A-skyrim%3F) might help

> To change the language of the subtitles in Skyrim, follow the below steps:
>
> 1. Open Documents folder.
> 2. Open My Games folder.
> 3. Open Skyrim folder.
> 4. Right-click on Skyrim.ini file, select Open With, and open with Notepad.
> 5. Change "sLanguage=ENGLISH" to "sLanguage=*" with "*" being whichever language you need.
> 6. Click File, then Save.

If you are on console, it may be more of a problem, as the console copies of the game were only given language options appropriate to their region of sale. Ensure your console primary language is set to English.